# Possible to get a transparent, borderless CMD prompt on the desktop for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, gui

I use Windows 7, but am a big fan of Linux. However for this computer, I have to run Windows and wanted a transparent always on terminal for my desktop, something like this:

[image: desktop with wanted CMD effect]

I tried using [Glass CMD](http://komalo.deviantart.com/art/Glass-CMD-for-Vista-and-Seven-121457868) and [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) but they're not the same.  How can I possibly get a similar desktop CMD prompt on Windows?

---

Thanks to Darth Android! I got my console2 working like I needed. also for any people who need to focus their console window, here's an autohotkey script.

```
Loop{
    if GetKeyState("LButton", "P"){
        if WinActive("ahk_class Progman"){
            MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
            if(xpos > 522){
                if(ypos < 475){
                    if WinExist("ahk_class Console_2_Main"){
                        WinActivate
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Karsetn Sperling specifically made [Alpha](http://spiff.de/alpha.html) as a way for Windows users to get a transparent command-prompt like in Linux, but it still has the window frame. Console windows are special and not handled like others, so even if you could find a program that lets you strip the frame from a normal window, it may not work for consoles (I just tried a couple of such programs and one did nothing while the other crashed).

Comment: You mentioned that Console/Console2 are not the same - I was able to get pretty close with it (see my answer), but I would be interested to know specifically which issues you had with it in case I missed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a program called [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to create this effect. I have mine set up with an auto-hotkey script to produce a quake-style drop-down terminal, but you could just as easily stick it to your desktop, set the background color to be completely transparent, and strip the window decorations:

[image]

If you want to get it *really* similar to your *nix terminal, install Cygwin and configure Console2 to launch bash instead of `cmd.exe` or PowerShell.

The only caveat with the setup is it's a bit difficult to focus the window due to the nature of Windows' color-keying (i.e., clicking on transparent pixels actually click *through* the window to the desktop, instead of giving it focus), but that can be fixed with an auto-hotkey script configured to listen for mouse-clicks in specific areas of the desktop, and then transferring focus to Console2, or by simply alt-tabbing to it if you're willing to leave the icon in the taskbar.

Comment: I'll try this out again, already have cygwin, so it should be okay

Comment: Yay, it worked! Accepted!

Comment: Hey, having a bit of trouble getting the focus, how would an autohotkey script work?

Comment: @TheEliteNoob It would be something along the lines of "Left Click -> if desktop is active window -> if mouse coordinates overlap the location of the console window -> focus the console window" (paraphrased) You can set a persistent window title to help with focusing the console window, and [so] or the autohotkey forums can help you nail down the details of the script. If it's still giving you trouble, I'll sit down this evening or tomorrow and see if I can get a script working.

Comment: Thanks, but I got it working, I'll edit my answer so other people can see it.